# Issue with importing my own library files from JitPack dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, jitpack

I'm facing an issue with importing library files from a JitPack dependency in my Android Studio project. I have followed the steps to add the JitPack dependency, and the Gradle build is successful. However, I am unable to import any of the library files into my code. It's worth mentioning that when I directly use the library's compiled .aar file in my project, everything works fine.

Here are the details of my setup:

1. The library module is hosted on GitHub, and I have uploaded a
   pre-compiled .aar file along with the pom.xml file in a specific
   branch of the repository.
2. In my project's build.gradle file, I have added the JitPack
   repository as a dependency source:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } }
```

3. hen, in the app module's build.gradle file, I have added the JitPack
   dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.username:repository:branch'
}
```

4. The library's pom.xml file, located in the repository's branch, has
   the following structure:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>consights</groupId>
    <artifactId>offerxp-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies required by the library module -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Despite successfully building the project with the JitPack dependency, I am unable to import any of the library files or use their classes in my code. There is also no entry for the groupId or version of the library in the Gradle cache.

What could be causing this issue? Am I missing any crucial steps or configurations? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.